# Supporting both This-User-Only and Local-Machine settings

Tags: windows, installation, registry

I have an application that has to support modifying some registry data depending on the kind of 'installation' that is desired. At present, I have no problems hard-coding to either get elevation and do the changes to the entire local machine, but it is far from nice as ideally, I would also like to support per-user installations. I could hardcode that, but then I lose the local-machine stuff. To be precise, the changes in question involve file association changes, COM stuff etc.

**How can I properly support both usage scenarios?** Currently I use a set of ON/OFF checkboxes for the variety of associations.

- Should I change this meaning on, for example, a MachineInstall file existing in my apps directory, and if not assume User install?
- Is it an expected/valid/whatever usecase to say that someone might want to do some things for the entire machine, and some things only for the user? (E.g. mixing of the two.)
- Or should I change the entire UI, move away from checkboxes and move to some sort of combobox going 'None/User/Local'? Then again, I think this might have some sort of breakage once you involve multiple users and combinations.

To give an indication, I personally expect the application in question to have its uses for everyone on a computer and as such lean towards the Local-Machine as a 'default', if that makes any sort of difference.

I am likely overthinking the matters quite a bit, so any and all input is very much appreciated. :)

**P.S.**

Now, someone is probably going to say 'do not do all that stuff from your app, do it from the installer instead'. And they probably have a point, but the point is to allow easy changing of these settings from within the application. To top it off, I am not using .MSI install packages because they make working with 32/64-bit specific executables a disaster requiring merge modules, spawning other MSI's depending on the situation, and so forth (I forgot the details last time I dug into it and forgot about the matter). I don't have that knowledge, nor the time to learn all the intricacies of MSI installations, so it is out for as far I am concerned. To boot, my application is perfectly capable of functioning without *any* of those registry entries being present, and that is by design. In a way, one might compare it to be like Process Explorer from Sysinternals, which does not require an installer, but can be unzipped and take over the task manager etc without a problem if a user wants, or simply run stand-alone.